# Installation Error while installing portia

Tags: python, portia

Followed instructions on the github page. Of course, had to make minor changes since I was working with a windows 7 system. I got to the point post creating the virtual environment for portia to run. And I was trying to install the required packages using pip.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It failed with a [log](http://pastebin.com/dAgSRnad).

Now in the shell I try to run twistd, it gives error saying command not found. I even tried as follows:

```
deostroll@DEOTOP /c/Portia/portia/slyd (master)
$ python ../../portia_env/Scripts/twistd.py -n slyd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../portia_env/Scripts/twistd.py", line 13, in <module>
    from twisted.scripts.twistd import run
  File "c:\Portia\portia_env\lib\site-packages\twisted\__init__.py", line 53, in
 <module>
    _checkRequirements()
  File "c:\Portia\portia_env\lib\site-packages\twisted\__init__.py", line 37, in
 _checkRequirements
    raise ImportError(required + ": no module named zope.interface.")
ImportError: Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later: no module named zop
e.interface.
(portia_env)
deostroll@DEOTOP /c/Portia/portia/slyd (master)
$
```

Is there an alternate procedure to follow in order to make this work on windows?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `zope.interface` didn't install when you ran:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Could you try running the following and see if it works?

```
pip install zope.interface
```